# Data SMS never delivered on Android Lollipop emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, sms, android-5.0-lollipop

I am trying to send a data SMS from one to another emulator instance using `SMSManager.sendDataMessage(...)`. Everything works fine when testing on two devices but the data SMS never gets delivered when using the emulator. Is this an emulator issue or am I missing something?

Comment: How is that possible? Could you send me a link? The idea is though to somehow simulate the sending of data SMS the same way normal SMS are sent from one emulator to another in order to avoid SMS sending costs.